# Change time when showing daily or weekly bundles in Google Inbox

Tags: inbox-by-gmail

In a Google Inbox bundle, you can specify when the messages should show:

[image]

My question is: Is it possible to change the times (in the red squares) anywhere?
What if I want to get my "Work"-bundle at 7am, but my "Private"-bundle at 6pm?
And my "Inspiring Emails" at Thursday 4am? You get the point.

Comment: I read that, but it there isn't anything in it answering my question, is there? As with the desktop client, it only gives me the three options in the picture above, not any way to change the times.

Comment: Okay, I understand.
Notifications aren't the same thing as "showing" a bundle.
A notification is what you get on your phone, as with any other app. Even if you set it not to notify you about emails, it shows up in your inbox.
If you set it to not be shown, on the other hand, it wont even be visible in the inbox until the set time. (If I have understood things.)

Comment: Would appreciate if you could share if you were able to modify this.

Comment: It still isn't possible, as far as I know. I'll add an answer if/when Google implements it.

Comment: I also sent feedback. It would be nice to change times at least.

I also have emails that relate to a weekly event and it would be nice to have them bundled and held back for 6 of the days but then 24 hours before the weekly event start showing the bundle on demand.

Comment: IIRC this is local time. You could change the time zone in your Google account...

Comment: Is this feature available in Gmail or any desktop based email client ( Linux based)?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because Inbox by Gmail was retired in April, 2019

Answer (score 12):

It is not currently possible to change this time. I have submitted feedback to Google regarding this as I also want to change it, however there currently is nothing that will allow you to change it at this time.

The only thing you can do which may help speed up the process of having such a feature added is to [submit feedback](https://support.google.com/inbox/answer/6067592?hl=en) regarding this Inbox feature.

Comment: Every time I run into something like this, I google it, and get an answer exactly like this. What an utterly broken, unfinished product Inbox is...

Comment: @aendrew Oh for sure. That is why I switched back to Gmail.

Comment: @ComputerLocus Is this feature available in Gmail or any desktop based email client ( Linux based)?